# Connect to the Magento API using C#

Tags: c#, web-services, api, magento

Im trying to connect to the Magento 1.4.0.1 API, but until now I have no luck.

I have added a `Service Reference` named `MagentoAPI` and pointed it to `http://mydomain.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1` (I know the `=1` is not intended, but it dont work without)

This works fine, I get a list of all available methods, but when I try to use any of them it dont work.

```
using Magento_Import.MagentoAPI;

namespace Magento_Import
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortType handler;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string session = handler.login("username", "password");
        }
    }
}
```

That is how I initialize the web service, but when I debug the code the `handler` is `null`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I got it working by doing this:

```
using Magento_Import.MagentoAPI;

namespace Magento_Import
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient handler = new Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string session = handler.login("username", "password");

            catalogProductEntity[] products;
            handler.catalogProductList(out products, session, null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

But im not sure this is the best practice, if anyone knows any better ways to do this please say so :D

Comment: It is very much so best practice to initialise your objects before using them. The reason handler is null is because you never set it to a value (ie. the value of the instance of a class).